# not publishing the form in Sharepoint site as a new form(Infopath) after changes are made to the existing form when opened

Tags: sharepoint-designer, infopath

How do I edit a Infopath form and not publish it onto the sharepoint library as a new form? I just want to make change to the old one and save it but not as as a new form. 
I'm working on a workflow where I send a mail with the link of the form to the manager. He has to open the form and change a particular field. Once, that's done, he should send a mail to second level approvers. I'm able to send a mail to the manager but when manager clicks on the link, it opens the form and the changes he made is saved into another new form. Now because of this, since a new form is created, the workflow is altered.
Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Create a Hidden Field
Add a Submit data connection
Add Custom Rules to Submit action
create a hidden field ->Drag-and-drop a text box control onto the form template’s view. Rename the text box to ‘filename’ and click OK. Then select the filename text box and hit delete to remove the field from the view.
Go to Tools, Data Connections and click Add. Create a new Connection to Submit data to a SharePoint document library.
[image]

Enter the document library, and click the fx button and Insert the field ‘fileName’ in order to give the form submitted the name stored under ‘fileName’. Select ‘Allow overwrite if file exists’.

[image]

Give the data connection a name example "UniqueName"

1. Goto Tools, Submit Options, and click on Rules select perform actions using custom rules
   [image]
2. Add rules as below
   [image]
3. RULE1: Set condition: when filename is blank
4. Set Action1 Set field’s value filename = concat (Myfield, now()); where myfield could be the field name you want to show on the form name(like title, contactname,date etc...)
5. in the filename=concat (Title, now());
6. Set  Action2 Submit using dataconnection use the one we created earlier i.e. "UniqueName"
7. Rule2 : Condition when filename is not blank
8. Action: submit using dataconnection same as in step 6
9. Once you have the two rules you can save and publish your form and will have no issues.

Comment: Can you please explain what the fileName is?  Is it a column in the library? If yes, can you also explain how does it get populated.
Thanks!

Comment: Updated the answer